# Syntax Error when rendering React Native ImageBackground

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

I am working with React Native following an app building tutorial. I have recreated what is in the tutorial, but when I preview on an Android simulator I get the following error which prevents rendering. I'm sure this is simple, but can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

JSX tags are like HTML tags. You're missing `>` to close the tag.

```
<ImageBackground
   style={styles.background}
   source={require("../../appbb.png")}
/>
```

or if there are children inside the `ImageBackground`

```
<ImageBackground
   style={styles.background}
   source={require("../../appbb.png")}
>
   <View />
</ImageBackground>
```